# Solve Ax=0 using Single Value Decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, matrix-decomposition

Trying to solve Ax=o when $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&-1\\1&2&1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ using single value decomposition. I have the s,v,u and was thinking that x was as simple as $x=s*s^t$ but that didn't seem to work when I checked it. I know that when Ax=b that $x=(A^tA)^{-1}b$ so it must be easier than that. Suggestions on an article or the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vectors which $Ax=0$ are in the null space of $A$. The null space of $A$ is spanned by the [right singular vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) corresponding to zero singular values.

Comment: Helped a bit but I am still not getting <0>. You say that the solution is the right singular vectors which are the eigenvectors of $A^T*A$. This is what I got in Matlab when running [u,s,v]=svd   v =\begin{bmatrix} -0.7071   & 0.4082  & -0.5774\\-0.7071 &-0.4082    &0.5774\\  0.0000  & -0.8165&   -0.5774 \end{bmatrix}  then when taking A*v I do not get the zero vector.

Comment: They are the right singular vectors corresponding to the *zero* singular values. The first two columns correspond to singular values 3 and 1.7321. The last  column corresponds to a zero singular value, and indeed if you do A*last column you will get zero.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Batman: Wikipedia states that for a matrix M "the right-singular vectors corresponding to vanishing singular values of M span the null space of M and the left-singular vectors corresponding to the non-zero singular values of M span the range of M." This must be based on the fundamental theorem of linear algebra which relates the SVD to the row space, column space, and null space - is there an analytical proof of this?